# Regex - Capture string following timestamp

Tags: regular-expression

Looking for an efficient Regex to capture the string following the time stamp in the following:

```
<38>Oct 10 14:32:29 UAT01 
<86>Oct 10 14:32:29 Test04 
<13>Oct 10 14:35:09 Dev02
<13>Oct 10 14:35:10 Test03
```

Comment: It's for extracting specific data from logs. I know how to capture the timestamp - https://regex101.com/r/hkyh08/1/

Comment: Needs to be Regex. It is for a SIEM. Need to capture the hostname that always appears after the timestamp in the logs.

Comment: That is correct. Looking for the proper way to capture the string that immediately follows the timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the question is asking for a regex specifically:

```
grep -Eo '\s(\w+).$' file

 UAT01 
 Test04 
 Dev02
 Test0
```

Explanation:

```
`\s` matches any whitespace character.
`(\w+)` is the first Capturing Group 
 `\w+` matches any word character  and it is equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]
 `+ ` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible.
 `.` matches any character (except for line terminators)
 `$` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string.
```

---

The last strings can be extracted much easier using `cut` or `awk`

```
cut -d' ' -f 7 file

awk '{print $7}' file
```